# Which is the best annotation tool for semantic web or onthologies?

Tags: semantic-web, owl, ontology

There is a list at http://annotation.semanticweb.org/tools/

Have you tried them? Any suggestion?

Comment: I wonder know the state of the art best tool. Today. Some of the tools in the link are dead, so I'd like to know if anyone is using some.

Comment: Try asking on http://www.semanticoverflow.com

Comment: Can't believe it exits! :) Thanks!

Comment: Juanjo asked the question there: http://www.semanticoverflow.com/questions/279/which-is-the-best-annotation-tool-for-semantic-web-or-onthologies

Answer (score 1):

The tools on that list are quite diverse. The SHOE thing and annotea are both quite old now, I probably wouldn't bother. Annozilla is a firefox plugin, that can also speak to the annotea server,it may be nicer and more modern, but I have not tried it.

There was another nice firefox extension for annotationgs, I forget exactly what it was, but it may have developed into this: http://www.zotero.org/ Looks interesting either way.